# How can i extend a model through a reusable app?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wrote an app that is mainly allowing the user to drag tags to objects via jQuery. I want to allow that app to work for multiple models, so that i can tag ie. a user or an image. For this i thought about adding a class containing a "dropcode" to each models representation on the page:

```
<div class="droppable" dropcode="drop_img"> some image </div>
<div class="droppable" dropcode="drop_user"> some user </div>
```

I would like to specify the "dropcode" for each of the models in the main projects settings:

```
droppable_models={User:'drop_user',Image:'drop_img'}
```

After installing the app, i want to be able to retrieve the dropcode from each instance of the affected models:

```
image_instance1.dropcode -> drop_img
image_instance2.dropcode -> drop_img

user_instance1.dropcode -> drop_user
user_instance2.dropcode -> drop_user
```

That way i could just simply use the dropcode on the page, return it via jQuery to select the right model

Is that possible? Is there a better way to achieve what i want do do?

Comment: By the way - the app i created doesn't have any models right now. There just are a bunch of views to handle the ajax-requests, for storing tags it uses the taggit app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the tips of Simon and Burhan i came to the following solution: I define the affected models in the settings and then add the DragToTagable Class as Base Class to those models. This look like that in the settings:

```
DROPPABLE_MODELS=('test.TestItem:item',)
```

Thats all that needs to be done to apply the apps functionality to that model, or any other model of my project. The model.py of my app looks like this now:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from django.conf import settings

try:
    #perform this when starting the project
    for definition in settings.DROPPABLE_MODELS:     
        #parse contenttype 
        parsed=definition.split(':')
        dropcode=parsed[1]
        parsed=parsed[0].split('.')
        appname=parsed[0]
        modelname=parsed[1]

        #get the models class for the specified contenttype
        model_class=ContentType(app_label=appname, model=modelname).model_class()

        #create class Mixin, containing the dropcode property
        class DragToTagable:
            dropcode = dropcode

        #add DragToTagable as a base class to the model class
        model_class.__bases__+=(DragToTagable,)

except AttributeError:
    pass

except:
    import sys
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

This way i do not have to create an additional table, like in burhans proposal. And the app stays completely independent and requires no work on existing models to be implemented.

Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

If your application should work with any model, then you should use the [contentypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/):

> Django includes a contenttypes application that can track all of the
>   models installed in your Django-powered project, providing a
>   high-level, generic interface for working with your models.

Implementing this allows your application to be generic - it can work with any installed model.

EDIT:

Here is how to use content types framework (directly from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag
```

Now, to add a tag to the item:

```
item = Model.object.get(pk=1)
ti = TaggedItem(tag='foo',content_object=item)
ti.save()
```

To get tags for a particular item:

```
i = Image.object.get(pk=1) # or any instance of the Image object, or any object
the_type_of_object = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(i)

# Find all tags for this object
image_tags = TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_type__pk=the_type_of_object.id,
                                       object_id=i.id)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I know about the contenttypes framework, and already suspected i should use that. But i can't wrap my brains around how to use it to achieve what i want... A hint where to start?

Comment: Well, thats about as far as i came with the django docs. But i would need a model for that in any case. As i use the taggit app to store the tags, i would prefer to avoid creating a new model. My app does not need to store any data, it just needs to create a few links between existing apps.

Comment: If you are creating links, the only way to store them is to use a model. I am not familiar with taggit, but if its anything like other tagging applications - I am sure its using content types somewhere. Perhaps you can customize that?

Comment: links just in a general sense, not in a sense of hyperlinks - maybe i should have written "logical connections". Anyway - i realised my problem is probably more about Python than about Django. I think i can solve it by dynamically assigning a property to the respective classes. Just have to find out how to retrieve that model via contenttypes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a `dropcode` property to the appropriate models? eg.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    ....
    dropcode = property(lambda self: "drop_img")
```

For existing models where you can't edit the `models.py` (such as `User` model), add code like this to the `models.py` of one of your own apps:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserMixin:
    dropcode = property(lambda self: "drop_user")
User.__bases__ += (UserMixin,)
```

Then in your template, use an `if` tag to check whether an item has a dropcode. You can therefore eliminate the `droppable_models` setting:

```
<div class="droppable"{% if item.dropcode %} dropcode="{{item.dropcode}}"{% endif %}>{{item}}</div>
```

Comment: Your proposals are not working, as the intention of a reusable app is NOT to change your other apps. Reusable apps should only need changes in the main url.py, the settings.py and the templates. What is the second proposal exactly doing? I think that could be a solution anyway.